# Am I doing this right? Converting a jQuery function to Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me preface this that I am in no way, shape, or form a web developer and I can write neither jQuery nor JavaScript. However, I know enough about building websites that I can read a lot of markup and get things done with copy and paste.

For an article I am writing, I need to turn a jQuery function into plain JS. I have hobbled it together from a number of tutorials on this topic and it works. However, seeing as I don't know what I am doing and before I publish advice to people who don't know any better, I thought it would be a good idea to ask people with actual knowledge to have a quick look if there are any obvious blunders or things I should change, which is what I am humbly requesting.

The original snippet is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.header').height($(window).height());
})
```

And here is what I turned it into:

```
var ready = (callback) => {
    if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();
    else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}

ready(() => { 
    document.querySelector(".header").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
})
```

Thanks in advance for any and all feedback!

Comment: Looks good, though personally I'd try to remove the `ready` and the `$(document).ready`s entirely by giving the script the `defer` attribute

Comment: For code review questions, please ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'll look into that, thank you!

Comment: @str I know this is now possible with CSS but it serves as an example for how to use JS/jQuery in Bootstrap

Comment: @trincot Sorry, didn't know that. Will do next time!

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: `I can write neither jQuery nor JavaScript` then you immediately proved yourself wrong by posting your JS code :)

Comment: @OrAssayag Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @JeremyThille Haha, it's mostly copy and paste tbh. The only thing I really wrote by hand was `+ "px"` if I'm not mistaken. Thanks for the comment, though!